# Unable to get solution correct for submission

Tags: python

It is a sample problem for practice ([here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest-problem/sahil-loves-gfg/0/)), and is not getting accepted due to it giving 'wrong answer'. It is compiling fine, but might be for different test inputs failing on submission.
I just request comment for the same, as hope that the issue must be small.

The problem statement is: 
The program should accept first line of input as no. of strings, s.t.  it is less than 10. And the next lines should contain one string each of length less than 100 characters. Need find occurrence of "gfg" in the strings.
If no occurrence is found, -1 should be returned.

```
#code
t = int(input())
if t > 10 or t<0:
    exit()
arr = [[0] for i in range(t)]
total = [[-1] for i in range(t)] 


for i in range(t):
    arr[i] = [k for k in input().split()[:1]]  
    for j in arr[i]:
        total[i] = j.count("gfg")
        if total[i]==0: total[i]=-1
        print (total[i])
```

Comment: arr[i] = input()

Comment: I would change your variable names to make more sense. This code isn't very readable. I understand it was for a practice exercise so readability was less important, but it becomes needed if you're going to post it on SO.

Comment: @HeXiao  failed by taking that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = int(input())
if t not in range(10):
    exit()
else:
    pass

total = []
for i in range(t):
    line = input()[:100]
    if line.count("gfg") == 0:
        total.append(-1)
    else:
        total.append(line.count("gfg"))

print('\n'.join(map(str, total)))
```

[image]

SOLUTION FOR YOUR TASK:

```
  t = int(input())
  total = []

  for i in range(1, t + 1):
      line = input()
      if len(line)<=100:

           count = 0
           for i in range(0, len(line) - 3 + 1):
               if line[i:i + 3] == "gfg":
                   count += 1
           if count != 0:
               total.append(count)
           else:
               total.append(-1)

  for i in total:
      print (i)
```

NOTE: your submitting was failing because of special cases

For example:
in string gfgfg, your substring "gfg" occurres 2 times, and in that case you can't use the string count() method

how you can see ,here **line[i:i + 3]** I am moving index by index and checking next 3 values (because your substing "gfg" have length 3)

Comment: failed in submision, can check at : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/contest-problem/sahil-loves-gfg/0/

Comment: but fails on submitting

Answer (score 0):

You are erasing the value of total[i] each time you iterate in the last loop :

```
>>> for j in arr[i]:
>>>    total[i] = j.count("gfg")
>>>    if total[i]==0:
>>>       total[i]=-1
>>>    print (total[i])
```

Do you want to count the occurences in each word or in the whole sentence ? Because then you just have to write :

```
>>> for i in range(t):
>>>    n_occ = input().count("gfg")
>>>    if n_occ != 0:
>>>       total[i] = n_occ
```

If there's no occurence you don't have to do anything because the value in total is -1 already.
Also, write:

```
>>> total = [-1]*t
```

not:

```
>>> total = [[-1] for i in range(t)]
```

Comment: wrong, can check this by adding : for i in range(t): print (total[i]). See code at: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_PFXUl8lkln_0.py

Comment: Yes, if the loop is about i. But here you loop over j and modify an index related to i.

Comment: Please  see the outer loop too.Had there been more than one string per line, then you would be right.

Comment: I've seen it. See, let's take i = 0. For each different j, you write total[0] = j.count("gfg") . You see that you're writing many times total[0]. Only the last writing will be available.

Comment: but only if more than one string per line seperated by blank space(s).